# React Router Nested Routes tries to return file source instead of component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am following the serverless-stack tutorial. 
I am creating `/notes/new` path to render the `NewNotes` component, however, instead of rendering my component, it seems like it's trying to find a file path?

error:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/notes/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Routes.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./containers/Home";
import Login from "./containers/Login";
import NotFound from "./containers/NotFound";
import Signup from "./containers/Signup";
import NewNote from "./containers/NewNote";
export default function Routes( props ) {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
      <Route path="/login" exact component={Login}  />
      <Route exact path="/signup" component={Signup}/>
      <Route exact path="/notes/new" component={NewNote} />
      { /* Finally, catch all unmatched routes */ }
      <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

When I check out the 404 error it seems to believe `/notes/new` is a file location rather than a component.

[image]

my App component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Nav, Navbar, NavItem } from "react-bootstrap"
import { LinkContainer } from "react-router-bootstrap"
import { onError } from "./libs/errorLib";
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify'
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify'
import { AppContext } from "./libs/contextLib";



import Routes from "./Routes"
import './css/index.css'

const App = (props) => {
  const [isAuthenticating, setIsAuthenticating] = useState(true);
  const [isAuthenticated, userHasAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  useEffect( ()=> {
    console.log(`isAuthenticated:${ isAuthenticated }`)
  }, [isAuthenticated])

  useEffect(() => {
    onLoad();
  }, []);

  async function onLoad() {
    try {
      await Auth.currentSession();
      userHasAuthenticated(true);
    }
    catch(e) {
      if (e !== 'No current user') {
        onError(e);
      }
    }

    setIsAuthenticating(false);
  }

  async function handleLogout() {
    await Auth.signOut();
    userHasAuthenticated(false);
  }

  useEffect( ()=>{
    console.log(`
      COGNITO_AWS_REGION:${process.env.COGNITO_AWS_REGION}
      COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID:${process.env.COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID}
      COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID:${process.env.COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID}
      COGNITO_APP_CLIENT_ID:${process.env.COGNITO_APP_CLIENT_ID}
      `)
  }, [])

    return (
      !isAuthenticating &&
      <div className="App container">
        <Navbar fluid collapseOnSelect>
          <Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Brand>
              <Link to="/">Scratch</Link>
            </Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle />
          </Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Collapse>
            <Nav pullRight>
              {isAuthenticated
                ? <NavItem onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</NavItem>
                : <>
                    <LinkContainer to="/signup">
                      <NavItem>Signup</NavItem>
                    </LinkContainer>
                    <LinkContainer to="/login">
                      <NavItem>Login</NavItem>
                    </LinkContainer>
                  </>
              }
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
        <AppContext.Provider value={{ isAuthenticated, userHasAuthenticated }}>
          <Routes />
        </AppContext.Provider>
      </div>
    );
}

var root = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>, root)
```

Comment: Is that `Switch` rendered within *some* `Router`? How are you trying to navigate to "/notes/new"?

Comment: @DrewReese it's pretty templated how I did that part in my App component BUT I did add it now. I just didn't want to make a bloated question. hopefully it helps :/

Comment: Thank you. I don't see if you are programmatically pushing to a "/notes/new" route or not from your update.

Comment: @DrewReese, for now, I'm just trying to go there by manually visit in the browser: `localhost:8080/notes/new`. I haven't made a space in the navbar to navigate to the component. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, just trying to verify that either (1) your code is pushing to the correct route, or (2) manually typing in the correct path. In other words, no typos. I'm curious why something is fetching "http://localhost:8080/notes/main.js" though.  If you render one of the other working components, like `Home` or `Login` does the path "/notes/new" work? If you change the pathname to "/notes/test" does `NewNote` component correctly load?

Comment: @DrewReese okay, so if I change login to `/notes/login` then it throws the same error except it's looking notes/login file now. When I do just `notes` for my NewNote component it renders my component. Meaning that my react component is fine. It's this extended path that's the problem :/  
my react-router is `5.1.2` the latest one so it's not outdated.